# Compiled (?) java packages on Debian

Tags: debian, apt, java

I notice looking for the jinput library on Debian (I believe the "j" here implies this is a java specific library, and not a simple wrapper), that there are two packages that might apply:

```
libjinput-java/stable 20100502+dfsg-7 all
  Java Game Controller API

libjinput-jni/stable 20100502+dfsg-7 armhf
  Java Game Controller API (jni)
```

Notice this is an ARM system.  I know other languages sometimes have two implementations of something, a faster one which requires compiling and a "pure whatever" (in this case java) which does not.  The latter seems an unlikely possibility here, but I don't know for certain; the fact that the first one shows up as a package applicable to "all" platforms is interesting vs. the second one, which is an architecture specific listing.

So what is the difference, in Debian nomenclature, between a `-java` package and a `-jni` package?

---

I'm now guessing the `-jni` package allows this library to be used "in reverse", i.e., from C/C++, if someone could confirm or deny that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`libjinput-java` and `libjinput-jni` are built from [the same source](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/jinput). The `-java` package contains the architecture-independent, pure Java JAR, and the `-jni` package contains the architecture-specific library which provides the native functionality required by the Java package. Notice that [`libjinput-java`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libjinput-java) depends on `libjinput-jni`: they're not two different implementations of jinput, they're two parts of jinput and both are required for jinput-dependent software to work.

The package separation is simply a case of splitting up architecture-independent files from architecture-specific ones.

(JNI is the [Java Native Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/), which allows programs running on a JVM to call code in native libraries.)